# Не работает сравнение строк Python

Tags: python, if

Имеется код ( Часть кода предоставил ниже )
При сравнении строк, даже если они одинаковые, переходит к else, даже не зайдя в if, может быть кто нибудь знает в чем дело?

````
cat_id = ['1', '17', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35']
cat_name = ["разработка сайтов", "тексты", "дизайн и арт", "программирование", "аутсорсинг и консалтинг", "аудио/видео", "реклама и маркетинг", "разработка игр", "переводы", "анимация и флеш", "фотография", "3d графика", "инжиниринг", "обучение и консультации", "оптимизация (seo)", "архитектура/интерьер", "полиграфия", "менеджмент", "мобильные приложения", "сети и инфосистемы", "веб-программирование", "дизайн сайтов", "верстка", "сайт «под ключ»", "контент-менеджер", "менеджер проектов", "интернет-магазины", "qa (тестирование)", "cms программисты", "доработка сайтов", "проектирование", "адаптивный дизайн", "юзабилити-анализ", "флеш-сайты", "wap/pda-сайты", "копирайтинг", "редактирование/корректура", "расшифровка аудио и видеозаписей", "рерайтинг", "контент-менеджер", "статьи", "сканирование и распознавание", "рефераты/курсовые/дипломы", "постинг", "стихи/поэмы/эссе", "тексты/речи/рапорты", "тексты на иностранных языках", "создание субтитров", "сценарии", "слоганы/нейминг", "резюме", "новости/пресс-релизы", "тз/help/мануал"
]
          try:
             user_special_main = html2.xpath(f'//*[@id="TopPanel"]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/a')[0].text # Возвращает str, которая точно присутствует в словаре cat_name

             for i in range(len(cat_name)):
                 print(f'{user_special_main} + {cat_name[i]}')
                 if user_special_main == cat_name[i]:
                     user_special_main = cat_id[i]
                     print(user_special_main)
                 else:
                     pass
          except Exception as e:
             print(e)
             user_special_main = '0'```
````

Comment: А зачем делать `user_special_main = cat_id[i]`? Да и если строка из `user_special_main` есть в `cat_name`, то проще без перебора проверить: `if user_special_main in cat_name:`

Comment: @gil9red, что бы определить ее место в списке, и вытащить из второго списка с числами, число которое находится на том же месте.

Comment: Я бы использовал словарь, где ключом будет слово, а значением то число. Плюс, нужно бы сразу выходить из цикла, т.к. после `user_special_main = cat_id[i]` дальнейшие проверки будут бессмысленными

Comment: Ладно... что выводит `print(repr(user_special_main))` перед циклом `for i in range(len(cat_name)):`?

Comment: @gil9red, print(repr(user_special_main)) 
 'Дизайн сайтов'

Comment: Ну вот, а у вас в том списке в маленьком регистре, поэтому и не работает сравнение. Приводите `user_special_main` в нижний регистр: `user_special_main = user_special_main.lower()`. Я бы еще на всякий добавил удаление пробелов: `user_special_main = user_special_main.strip().lower()`

Answer (score 0):

1. Скорее всего дело в пробелах.
2. Лучше использовать словарь. Если уж не словарь, а массив, то массив объектов с полями. Синхронизированные массивы - так себе вариант.
3. Судя по тому, что ты парсишь ссылки, я бы вообще попробовал доставать id из href, а не хардкодить.

Comment: В href не имеется id, id это лично ручками присвоил всем возможным вариациям.